# Docker compose - python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I want to create with docker-compose 2 Docker containers. 1 for DB (Postgres) and 1 for web (Django). Here are my files

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build: ./portal
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./portal/.env
  db:
    image: postgres:13p.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=portal
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=portal
      - POSTGRES_DB=sterling

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base cairo-dev cairo cairo-tools \
    # pillow dependencies
    jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev

RUN pip install "flask==1.0.1" "CairoSVG==2.1.3"

COPY ./requirements/base.txt .

RUN \
 apk add --no-cache python3 postgresql-libs && \
 apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev \
 libxml2 libxml2-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
 apk add libxslt-dev && \ 
 python3 -m pip install -r base.txt --no-cache-dir && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps

# copy project
COPY . .
```

when i run `docker-compose up` it throws me the following error:

```
web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Do you have an idea why docker-compose doesn't find my file when starting?

Comment: The `volumes:` are overwriting everything you `COPY` into the image, and at a glance it looks like the filesystem layouts might be different (is there an `app` subdirectory or not?).  Does removing the `volumes:` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `volumes` from `docker-compose.yml` and build again.

There is an issue with `docker-compose` on ubuntu. it can't mount the volume. And as I can see you want to mount . to `/usr/src/app`

and make sure you build the image again after you update the code.